# электронная подписть php с#

Tags: php, c#, шифрование, цифровая-подпись

У меня есть сервер на php и клиент на c# ( unity ). На сервере( рhp ), нужно зашифровать строку с помощью приватного ключа так, чтобы на клиенте( c# ) можно было проверить, правильно ли зашифрована строка. Метод шифрования не имеет значения - главное, чтобы шифровка была на php, а дешифровка - c#.

Буду рад любой помощи)

Comment: ну а чему тут помогать? Ну надо так надо - шифруйте на здоровье. Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Смотрите здесь - [System.Security.Cryptography](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netframework-4.8) - какие возможности есть в C#. Выбираете то, что есть и в php.